# How to Upload File in Katlon Studio for REST API

Tags: automation, build-automation, katalon-studio

I tried to verify one of my REST API responsible for uploading file using below code,

```
def builder = new RestRequestObjectBuilder()

//Create a new POST object using builder
def requestObject = builder.withRestRequestMethod('POST')
.withRestUrl(GlobalVariable.APIurl + '/add_track')
.withHttpHeaders([
  new TestObjectProperty('Content-Type', ConditionType.EQUALS, 'multipart/form-data'),
         new TestObjectProperty('key', ConditionType.EQUALS, GlobalVariable.key),
         new TestObjectProperty('token', ConditionType.EQUALS, GlobalVariable.token)])

.withMultipartFormDataBodyContent([
    new FormDataBodyParameter('file',"C:\\SampleAudio.mp3" , 'File'),
    new FormDataBodyParameter('description', 'This track is uploaded by automation',  'PARAM_TYPE_TEXT'),
    new FormDataBodyParameter( 'title', 'being single', 'PARAM_TYPE_TEXT'),
])
.build()

def response =WS.sendRequest(requestObject)
WS.verifyResponseStatusCode(response, 200)
WS.verifyElementPropertyValue(response, "message", "test")
```

But file is not posted on server, i tried all the possible ways but no luck.